# Where to find references for Sencha Touch

Tags: reference, sencha-touch

I wanted to learn Sencha touch.  the problem is i don't know Ext JS programming.  I have intermediate background with jquery, html, php ad sql.  I also have started using jquery mobile and phonegap, but I found that jquery mobile has loads of bugs so I decided to give sencha touch a try.  I have checked their well documented API docs but I find it difficult to understand the flow and the syntax.

I also found the book Sencha In Action by manning publications but it looks like this is not out for public use yet.

Can anyone with good knowledge about sencha direct me the better way to start? Do I have to learn Ext JS first?  I found loads of books about Ext JS in amazon.  A beginner's approach would be helpful.

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend you to follow this tutorial step by step. It helped me a lot. Thanks to Jorge for his wonderful example.Here is the link.

http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Some people will say you should check out the Ext JS books to establish a foundation with the framework first as the two are very similar. However, I would recommend that while that may be fine for most folk, you would now be learning two frameworks. They are siblings, not twins.

Have a look at the Sencha Touch Cookbook that was just published, follow the tutorials and cruise the threads, both here and the Sencha Forum.

Also note that Sencha Touch 2 Beta 1 was just released yesterday and it is way closer to Ext JS4 than ST1 and if you start with ST2, you might be better off going this route.

http://www.packtpub.com/sencha-touch-for-creating-cross-platform-html5-apps-cookbook/book
http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-raising-the-bar/